# SQL Server on Ubuntu: cannot enumerate files on other Ubuntu

Tags: sql

I have an installation:
Windows based LAN
Ubuntu 20.04 and SQL Server 2022
Ubuntu 22.04

Ubuntu 22.04 has Shared directory. It is visible in File Explorer on Windows and in Ubuntu 20.04 too as a remote shared folder. OK.
But when I run SQL Query on SQL Server (Ubuntu 20.04) and want to see the file list I have empty list only and no any errors

```
SELECT * FROM sys.dm_os_enumerate_filesystem(N'//192.168.0.153/koblenz/', N'*.*')
where is_directory=0
```

But when I open this link in Files on the same Ubuntu 20.04 I see all files.
What is wrong?

Comment: With apologies on behalf of the community, it looks like your question was spammed by a trio of bots that seems to be posting multiple AI-generated answers on questions. Unfortunately, the majority of the Moderators on Stack Exchange sites (including Ask Ubuntu) are on strike *primarily* because the parent company has reduced their ability to remove these bogus answers.  We're hoping that things get back to normal shortly, but in the meantime, we're having to deal with stuff like this.  At some point, the AI-generated answers below will be removed.